# xcode 9 Module file's minimum deployment target is ios11.2 v11.2

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I had create a swift framework, add the framework to app project and get error "`Module file's minimum deployment target is ios11.2 v11.2`"

[image]

In the framework project I made iOS Deployment Target to iOS 8.0

[image]

Do I still miss something?

Comment: Having this problem as well. Have changed to the correct deployment target AFAIK, deleted derived data etc, but the problem persists.

Comment: It seems a dependent module target is ios11.2 v11.2.

Comment: I've had this problem, when removing the Framework from the app project you chose "Move to trash" and when copying it back you select the option "Copy items if needed"